# Regular expression for count lesson absence of students

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I store lesson absence of students in database with comma seperated values.

I do count comma's as regex to count how many lessons student was absent.

this is how I do it.

```
@foreach($students as $student)

   {{(preg_match_all('/[^,]+/',DB::table('discontinuities')
->where('student_id', $student->id)
->where('type2','absent')->pluck('type2Lesson'))) }} 
    Lessons student was absent.
@endforeach
```

but the problem is student can be absent multiple days which means multiple rows are stored in **discontinuities** table this query shows the only first value returning. but I need to sum total values to return how many lessons student was absent

this is example of absent lessons by student

[image]

and this is the query of results

[image]

**Edit:**

If I enter 2 absence first and then 1 absence

[image]

then the result is

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with that regex, count the number of commas in the `type2Lesson` field?

Comment: How do you know which output belongs to which student? You should at least output the student's name or ID or something, to be sure you are looking at what you think you are looking at.

Comment: @Jeff yes I do count number of comma seperated values but in multiple rows.

Comment: @trincot How do you know which output belongs to which student? I check with ->where('student_id', $student->id)

Comment: Yes, but you loop over student ids, so how do you know which line belongs to which student ID?

Comment: Doesn't `\w+,?` work? Match at least 1 alphanumeric characters followed by one or no comma's

Comment: @trincot I store students in different table and discontinuities in other table I check id's from student table and this is student_id in table discontinuities.

Comment: Arggh, we are talking different things. I am talking about the output and the interpretation of the output. The code you have will output "1 Lessons ...", "2 Lessons ...", "1 Lessons", but it does not display for which student each of the lines are output.

Comment: I know that Laravel is cross database engine, but which database engine are you using. MySql?

Comment: Jeff's answer solved my problem @trincot if you want to know more about my database schema you can send me an email rodrane@gmail.com I'll explain it briefly thank you

Comment: My question was not about the database schema, but about the output. Anyway, with the info I got, I also answered as I think my suggestion is worth considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach($students as $student)

<?php $absences = DB::table('discontinuities')
    ->select('type2Lesson')
    ->where('student_id', $student->id)
    ->where('type2','absent'))
    ->get();

    $count = 0;

    foreach($absences as $absence){
        $count += count(explode(',', $absence->type2Lesson));
    }
?>

   {{$count}} lessons student was absent.
@endforeach
```

This should work.  It isn't a good practice to keep data in json or CSV format in a database, because you end up having trouble writing queries to do what you want.  It would be best to have for instance a database of every class a student was supposed to attend and a boolean for absent or not.  Then you could just count the absences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a query that will group the absence records for a given student together. I would even let the query do the count of absence days. It could count the commas and then do a standard `->sum()` over that value:

```
@foreach($students as $student)

    {{ 
    DB::table('discontinuities')
    ->where('student_id', $student->id)
    ->where('type2','absent')
    ->sum(DB::raw("LENGTH(type2Lesson) - LENGTH(REPLACE(type2Lesson, ',', ''))+1")
    }}
    Lessons student was absent.
@endforeach
```

The query needs a **DB::raw()** call to calculate the number of commas. The syntax of that expression is database engine dependent. The above works for MySql, but for other database you need to use `LEN` instead of `LENGTH`.